Writing kanji with furigana in a table
I figured out how to write kanji (such as 西 -- west) in LaTeX with furigana (which is just its reading with hiragana -- にし for 西) on top of a kanji in the text of a paragraph. To do this, I use the package ruby (see code at the end of the post) and use its main command
\ruby{西}{にし}

to get 'にし' displayed on top of '西' in a smaller font (see figure below). The size of the "ruby base" (西 in the example) is determined by the font size of the document, the size of the ruby text (にし in the example) can be changed with
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.6}

where, I guess, 0.6 is a multiplier of the document's font size, and the separation between the furigana and the kanji can be changed with
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-1.0em}

Now I want write the same in the cells of tabulars, but I cannot get the furigana to be written on top of the kanji: the furigana overlaps with the kanji (see picture below).
How can I write kanji with furigana on top in the cell of a tabular using ruby? If it cannot be done, what other packages are there to write kanji with furigana that work inside tabulars?

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{ruby}
% separation between ruby base (kanji) and ruby text (furigana)
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-1.0em}
% size of ruby text (furigana)
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.6}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[margin=2.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{2}
\ruby{西}{にし}~\\

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule

\ruby{北}{ほく}\ruby{西}{せい} & 北[きた]  & 北東[ほくとう] \\[5ex]
\ruby{西}{にし}      &                       & 東[ひがし] \\[2ex]
南西[なんせい] & 南[みなみ] & 南東[なんとう] \\
\midrule
North-West & North & North-East \\
West       &       & East \\
South-West & South & South-East \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


The ruby package uses \baselineskip, but this is set to zero in tables. Change it to use \normalbaselineskip.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho ProN} % or any font supporting kanji
% separation between ruby base (kanji) and ruby text (furigana)
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-1em}
% size of ruby text (furigana)
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.6}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setstretch{2}

\xpatchcmd{\ruby}{\baselineskip}{\normalbaselineskip}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\ruby}{\baselineskip}{\normalbaselineskip}{}{}

\begin{document}

\ruby{西}{にし}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule

\ruby{北}{ほく}\ruby{西}{せい} & 北[きた]  & 北東[ほくとう] \\[5ex]
\ruby{西}{にし}      &                       & 東[ひがし] \\[2ex]
南西[なんせい] & 南[みなみ] & 南東[なんとう] \\
\midrule
North-West & North & North-East \\
West       &       & East \\
South-West & South & South-East \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


